# Creating a meeting scheduler

Tags: prolog, scheduler

I've been assigned to develop a program in Prolog that schedules meetings using restrictions.

**Concept**

There are a number of meetings and for each meeting there is a number of participants where some of them are obligatory to attend and others are optional. Each meeting also has a duration and a specific type of room that should be assigned to it. There are 3 different types of rooms with each type having its own capacity.

The goal is to maximize the number of optional participants and make sure there aren't meetings at the same place at the same time, that all the obligatory participants will be attending and that the meeting takes place in the type of room it should.

Honestly I am not sure how to approach this issue let alone make it. I could us some help.

Here is the "database" I created:

```
%Participants ID
participantID(1).
participantID(2).
participantID(3).
participantID(4).
participantID(5).
participantID(6).
participantID(7).
participantID(8).
participantID(9).
participantID(10).
participantID(11).
participantID(12).

%Meeting(name, duration, obligatory participants, optional participants)
meeting(thesis_presentation,1,[12,3,5],[1]).
meeting(company_meeting,1,[10,3],[5]).
meeting(chairman_election,3,[1,2,3],[4,5,6]).

%Placement(meeting, type)
place(meeting(thesis_presentation), auditorium).
place(meeting(company_meeting), normal).
place(meeting(chairman_election), auditorium).

%Rooms(id, type, capacidade) -> Regular=normal, Auditorium=projector, Conference Room=videoconference
room(1,normal, 5).
room(2,normal, 5).
room(3,normal, 5).
room(4,conference_room, 10).
room(5,conference_room, 10).
room(6,auditorium, 15).
```

Comment: I think the general idea is to perform a search: so you assign a meeting to a certain room with certain people, and you exploit Prolog's backtracking mechanism to ensure that if a conflict occurs you backtrack. I'm afraid however this question will be closed since it is rather broad.

Comment: Furthermore this assignment looks to make not much sense, since one could simple schedule all meetings the one next to the other one. In that case all optional participants can definitely participate.

Comment: @CommuSoft I understand, but the approach is actually by means of restrictions, using the clpfd library.

Comment: will in that case, you will first have to restrict *time*: set an upper and lower bound.